# How do I save arrays in arrays into files?

Tags: node.js, multidimensional-array

So I have an array in an array to make it simple I'll pretend it's:

```
var list_in_list = [[[1, 1], [2, 2]], [[2, 2], [1, 1]]]
```

So I want it saved into a file so I do:

```
fs.writeFile('sampletextfile.txt', list_in_list[1], function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('Saved!');
});
```

and in sampletextfile.txt it returns

```
2,2,1,1
```

Now I can't tell the first list from the second list. Is there any way of getting around this?

Comment: I would recommend jsonifying it before hand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
const fs = require('fs');

const list_in_list = [[[1, 1], [2, 2]], [[2, 2], [1, 1]]]

fs.writeFile('sampletextfile.txt', JSON.stringify(list_in_list[1]), function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('Saved!');
});
```